# Java Modulo Function Gives Zero

Tags: java, random, modulo, zero

Edit: Requesting deletion of this question from a moderator. It was a silly mistake and should not burden the community as a waste of resources.

In response to comments, yes I know about the delete button. Upon pressing it, I get a dialogue box. "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead." Any way around this?

Comment: You have the power to delete it yourself mate.  It's below the next to "edit" and "close"

Comment: @InfernalRapture Apparently not. "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead."

Answer (score 6):

If you divide something by 1...the remainder is always 0.

`%` returns the remainder of dividing the left by the right.